# Problems doing request with retrofit in android and API asp.net core

Tags: android, asp.net-core, retrofit

I am developing an android app using retrofit and my API asp.net core, I had to do the upgrade from windows 8 to windows 10, before with windows 8 retrofit did the request very well but now in windows 10 not.

Here is my code:

```
public interface API{
    @GET {"user"}
    Call<List<User>> getUser(@Query("username") String user, Query("password") String password);
    }
```

From where I do request :

```
protected Boolean doInBackground(void... params){ 

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder() 
            .baseUrl("http://localhost:4588/api/auth/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();

             API api = retrofit.create(API.class); 
    Call<List<User>> call = api.getUser("username", "password");

    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<User>>(){ 
         @override 
         public void onResponse(Call<List<User>> call, Response<List<User>> response){
              String text; 
              if(response.isSuccessful()){
              text = "success";
         } 
    }); 
    }
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Check if your api is accessible from your phone. My best guess is port has changed or you firewall rules got messed up